# add a sequence number to every sub-block of True value in column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a boolean column, every time a block of `True` value occurs in the column, I want to count that as one event. I tried, `cumcount` and `groupby.ngroup` to see if I can find a solution from there. `cumcount` doesn't count `False` values which is useful, but unable to figure out where to go from there. So I want to create a new colum `event_number` in a dataframe.

*Assumption: The data is correctly sorted.*

```
import pandas as pd

mydata = {"event_bool": [False,False,False,True,True,True,True,False,False,True,True,True,
                        False,False,False,True,True,True,True,False,False,True,True,True]}

# expected result - '0' can be something else like NaN
myresult = {"event_bool": [False,False,False,True,True,True,True,False,False,True,True,True,
                        False,False,False,True,True,True,True,False,False,True,True,True],
           "event_number": [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,3,3,3,3,0,0,4,4,4]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(myresult)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
df = df.reset_index()
df['rank'] = df[df.event_bool]['index'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()
df.drop('index', axis=1, inplace=True)
df['rank'] = df['rank'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

|  | event_bool | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | False | 0 |
| 1 | False | 0 |
| 2 | False | 0 |
| 3 | True | 1 |
| 4 | True | 1 |
| 5 | True | 1 |
| 6 | True | 1 |
| 7 | False | 0 |
| 8 | False | 0 |
| 9 | True | 2 |
| 10 | True | 2 |
| 11 | True | 2 |
| 12 | False | 0 |
| 13 | False | 0 |
| 14 | False | 0 |
| 15 | True | 3 |
| 16 | True | 3 |
| 17 | True | 3 |
| 18 | True | 3 |
| 19 | False | 0 |
| 20 | False | 0 |
| 21 | True | 4 |
| 22 | True | 4 |
| 23 | True | 4 |

Answer (score 2):

using `pandas` and `numpy.where`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)

df['event_number'] = np.where(
    df['event_bool'].eq(True),
    (df['event_bool'].ne(df['event_bool'].shift()) & df['event_bool'].eq(True)).cumsum(),
    0)
```

---

```
print(df)


    event_bool  event_number
0        False             0
1        False             0
2        False             0
3         True             1
4         True             1
5         True             1
6         True             1
7        False             0
8        False             0
9         True             2
10        True             2
11        True             2
12       False             0
13       False             0
14       False             0
15        True             3
16        True             3
17        True             3
18        True             3
19       False             0
20       False             0
21        True             4
22        True             4
23        True             4
```

---

```
df.to_dict(orient='list')

{'event_bool': [False, False, False, True, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True], 'event_number': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
mydata = {"event_bool": [False,False,False,True,True,True,True,False,False,True,True,True,False,False,False,True,True,True,True,False,False,True,True,True]}

event_number = []
true = 1

for i in range(len(mydata['event_bool'])):
    if mydata['event_bool'][i] == True:
        if mydata['event_bool'][i-1] == False:
            true = true+1
            event_number.append(true-1)
        else:
            event_number.append(true-1)
    else:
        event_number.append(0)
print(event_number)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4]
```